# Extraer datos de una cadena de caracteres

Tags: java

Tengo esta cadena de caracteres:

```
"Tel:1234567890 Email:example93@hotmail.com"
```

y quisiera que la salida fuera:

```
1234567890
example93@hotmail.com
```

Es decir, extraer esos datos para luego utilizarlos.

Probé hacer un doble split para obtener dos conjuntos de datos, pero no me estaría funcionando.

Comment: Hola. Por favor agrega su codigo aqui para que podemos examinar donde esta el error.

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar el código donde ejecutas los comandos '.split'? Sería más fácil para orientarte donde se encuentra el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

```
string cadena = "Tel:1234567890 Email:example93@hotmail.com";

string telefono = cadena.split(" ")[0].split(":")[1]; // "1234567890"
string email = cadena.split(" ")[1].split(":")[1]; // "example93@hotmail.com"
```

No se bien si te referías a eso por que al no ver tu código no te puedo ayudar bien pero creo que la respuesta es esa ya que split hace lo siguiente:

del string

```
string cadena = "hola que tal";
```

Si se le hace cadena.split(" ") nos va a quedar un array con los valores {"hola", "que", "tal"}

Al igual que si se le hiciese un cadena.split("a") obtendríamos {"hol", " que t", "l"}